# How to Transfer data from Google cloud storage to S3 without any manual activity?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

I want to transfer data from my cloud storage bucket to S3. I did a lot of research . I found an interesting article in which this can be done using gsutil command. Again it requires a manual activity. Is there any way to do this without any manual activity or like any possibility to run this gsutil command through Java API ?

I have created a VM instance on my Google cloud project.I have configured the boto file which has my AWS credentials.Using gsutil command I was able to copy my data from cloud storage to s3.I want to automate this step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gsutil` can work with both Google Storage and S3.

```
gsutil rsync -d -r gs://my-gs-bucket s3://my-s3-bucket
```

You just need to configure it with both - Google and your AWS S3 credentials. [`gsutil` would use credentials from `~/.boto` file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025324/google-cloud-using-gsutil-to-download-data-from-aws-s3-to-gcs)

There are multiple ways to automate shell command execution. From Java's Runtime.exec() to [Google Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) (your cloud's cron)

Comment: Thanks for the information.Yeah I have tried the boto file. I have added the command in .bat file and using Java's ProcessBuilder()  I could able to run the code locally in my tomcat server.When the same piece of code deployed in GCS , it is throwing some error. Can you help me how to run my .bat in GCS ?

Comment: Running .bat file might be tricky unless you have your own Windows instance running for that. Check out my next answer on Google Storage Transfer. It might be just what you need without any programming.

Comment: I just wanted  to add that if you chose gsutil rsync, it will not simply transfer the data but will [mirror](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync#description) your GCS to your S3, meaning if you delete an object from GCS it will also be deleted from S3.

Comment: @Anton ,Will hosting a dedicated internet facing server where the google sdk is installed will solve the issue?.

Comment: @JeorgeA - there are few flags to rsync such as -r -d that would let you control exact behaviour, so "mirror" is just one of the multiple options. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync

Comment: *dedicated internet facing server* is indeed an option you might use. It might incur ongoing costs for running this server.

Answer (score 0):

Fully automated and easy to use way would be [Google Storage Transfer](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/). It would let you select the source and target buckets in either S3 or GCS and set shedule such as "run daily at 1am"

Comment: I had gone through the document.It clearly mentions that it is used for data import into the GCS.

Comment: Oh, these cloud vendors! They indeed don't give you an easy way to move data out. Only in. Configuration tool gives you a few options to select "Source" and only one for "Target". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I didn't understand the point.Is there any configuration in the Storage transfer to move data out  ?.

Comment: @Dipu, no I can't find any. It should be pretty straightforward for Google to implement one since they have it in the opposite direction already. They just seem to choose not to.

Answer (score 0):

[Skyplane](https://github.com/skyplane-project/skyplane) is a much faster alternative for transferring data between clouds (up to 110x for large files). You can transfer data with the command:

```
skyplane cp -r s3://aws-bucket-name/ gcs://google-bucket-name/
```